# Setup Tor/vidalia with vmware workstation

Tags: networking, vmware, tor

I have tor/vidalia installed and works perfectly with whatever browser on host (windows 7) I point to 127.0.0.1:8118 proxy.

But how can I set it up from inside of vmware workstation guest (windows 7) without installing it on the guest?

Best i could google was https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/VMWareThroughTor

It says

```
Open privoxy setup file config.txt and modify the line (substituting your IP address found above and favorite port.): 

 {{{listen-address 127.0.0.1:8118 to: listen-address 192.168.23.1:8118}}}
```

I tried to put it in torrc configuration from vidalia but it "doesn't recognize the action".

**edit:** screen shot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wupk7.png

Do I need privoxy installed too? Can't it work directly through torrc configuration?

Comment: "_I tried to put it in torrc configuration from vidalia but it "doesn't recognize the action"._" can you describe what you did exactly?

Comment: @curiousguy [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/nLAIO.png)

Comment: Your config file does not look right... I think you first need to determine the correct local IP address (maybe not `192.168.23.1`), and then put in place of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @curiousguy But the "{{{listen-address" thing is giving the error, even if I figure out correct IP address how do I go about correcting that "Unrecognized option" error??

Comment: I think you need to change `SocksListenAddress 127.0.0.1` to  `SocksListenAddress 192.168.x.y`.

Answer (score 0):

you are editing tor configuration file and that is wrong

you need to install privoxy, edit the main configuration file by adding (listen-address 192.168.23.1:8118) and then restart privoxy

and that is all